# Too many mySql events

Tags: php, mysql, events

I am working on a classifieds ad website. And i need to ad a feature where the ads automatically change the status from active to inactive in 30 days. Currently I am planning mySql events and my question here is that there will be numerous ads and an event to every ad. So will it cause trouble or will slower the server? Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: It may be easier for your queries to just not pick up ads more than 30 days old.  Then at some point either archive or delete these ads if needed.

Comment: That was something I planned initially however there is an option where people can reactivate the ad which wont get deactivated in 30 days.

Comment: Add  `start_date` and `duration` columns to your table or a simple `end_date`. Then only select for display those that are less than `start_date + duration`. This adds flexibility for when someone wants an ad to run for 40 days, and you can run an Archive script once a month to get rid of old Ads. _Be careful about over engineering what can be reduced to a simple process_

Comment: That is a very good idea.. Never thought of it that way !!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with EVENTs myself now and pondered the same :)

In addition to the above answers:

- Use EVENTs if the task is purely data-centric, or complements
  functionality that is already build into the database. You may
  already have triggers that clean up data, log certain events,
  aggregate certain data, etc. If the scheduled task you want to
  perform is part of the existing design, it's more cohesive to trigger
  the task from an EVENT. EVENTs are temporal triggers after all.
- If you run a script from a shell, you need a username/password stored
  in the shell script or in a defaults file. For executing EVENTs, you 
  don't need a username/password after the EVENT has been created.
- IMCO you should write the logic in a stored procedure; then invoke
  the procedure from an EVENT or from a shell script, whatever suits
  you best. You might even build some place in your UI that enables
  users to invoke the procedure manually.

Comment: Will surely take it in consideration !!